# Looping through cells in a sheet and loading it to another

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to use appscript to loop through and transform a data set. After that, load to another sheet.

Currently only found solutions to loop by the row, and copying by range. (code not mine)

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheets = ss.getSheets();
var lines =  SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEET ID");
//
//
var sheet = lines.getSheetByName("Main")
var linevalues = sheet.getRange("A:F").getValues();
var lastrow=sheet.getLastRow();
```

If the first sheet has the dataframe:

```
[apple, 2]
[orange, 3]
```

It should append to a new sheet:

```
[apple, 1]
[apple, 2]
[orange, 1]
[orange, 2]
[orange, 3]
```

Comment: are First sheet=Main? and new sheet= create new sheet? how many sheets that will be involved?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I was about to ask "what's a dataframe?" until I noticed that it is a term used in python. Does your question rely on python? If it does, then would you please add a "python" tag to your question; and if it doesn't, then we're back to "what's a dataframe"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, by using the following code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Main");
  var resultSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Result");
  var linevalues = mainSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var results = [];
  for (var i=0; i<linevalues.length; i++) {
    var row = linevalues[i];
    for (var j=1; j<=row[1]; j++) {
      results.push([row[0], j]);
    }
  }
  resultSheet.getRange(1, 1, results.length, results[0].length).setValues(results);
}
```

You should obtain the following results:

- Before (Sheet "Main")

[image: before main sheet]

- After (Sheet "Result")

[image: after result sheet]

Note that in order to obtain these results, you will need a Spreadsheet with two Sheets, matching the names above. If you have any questions about the code please don't hesitate to ask back.